# Clicking buttons with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to learn how to make a script with AppleScript to click on a button on a web page with this script but before the end tell and everything obviously It first needs to open a web page that's the script but I want it to click something on it
here is the script

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"nonya"})
    end tell
end tell
```

I want the clicking button script in this script but before the end tell's

Comment: A concrete solution strongly depends on the structure of the website (your *URL* is meaningless) and if it's possible to click the button with javascript or not.

Comment: vadain it is possible for apple script and im asking for help to learn

Comment: not javascript that Im saying

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you need to have the website ready.  Once you do, if you know have an ID of the button, you can make AppleScript run a JavaScript in Safari or other browsers:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript document.getElementById('buttonID').click();" in document 1
end tell
```

Comment: 1. There is not an expressed need to preface the `do JavaScript` _command_ with the `return` _command_, and generally speaking there is just no need too. -- 2. Not all _elements_ have an `id`, e.g. the **Ask Question** _button_ on this page does not have an `id` by which to click it, it has `class="ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary"`. So, `do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();" in document 1` would be necessary, and to complicate this the _index_ needs to be the correct one too (, which in this case it is).

Comment: 1. Yes, the return is not needed, didn't bother to remove it when I picked up the code from my working example. 2. ID was an example,  any selector would work, and you just have to work it out to find that unique element.

Comment: thx but what do I put in the click id and button id how do I find that and what is return for and also I asked for u to customize it to be similar to my script